# Token based authorization results in an Unauthorized 401

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-httpauth

**Package versioning**

```
Flask          1.0.2
Flask-HTTPAuth 3.2.4
Flask-RESTful  0.3.8
itsdangerous   0.24
```

I'm working on a API project where a `POST` request to a Todo resource requires an user to have a token. Upon trying to test for this scenario, I'm getting the following assertion error: `AssertionError: 401 != 201`. Both `BasicHTTPAuth` and `TokenHTTPAutth` from  flask-HTTPAuth  are handling Authorization credentials.

Based on a User having a token to access this resource, I'm not clear on why I'm getting an `Unauthorized` error.
**tests.py**

```
class TestAuthenicatedUserPostTodo(ApiTestCase):
    '''Verify that an API user successfully adds a Todo'''

    def setUp(self):
        super().setUp()
        previous_todo_count = Todo.select().count()

        user = User.get(User.id == 1)
        token_serializer = Serializer(SECRET_KEY)
        self.token = token_serializer.dumps({'id': user.id})

    def test_todo_collection_post_todo_success(self):
        with app.test_client() as client:
            http_response = client.post(
                "/api/v1/todos/",
                headers={
                    'Authorization': f"Bearer {self.token}"
                },
                content_type="application/json",
                data={
                    "name": "Must do a todo",
                    "user": 1
                }
            )
        current_todo_count = Todo.select().count()

        self.assertEqual(http_response.status_code, 201)
        self.assertGreater(current_todo_count, previous_todo_count)
```

**auth.py**

```
basic_auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
token_auth = HTTPTokenAuth(scheme="Bearer")
auth = MultiAuth(token_auth, basic_auth)

@basic_auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    try:
        api_user = User.get(User.username == username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    user_verified = api_user.check_password(password)
    if user_verified:
        g.user = api_user
        return True
    return False

@token_auth.verify_token
def verify_token(token):
    timed_serializer = Serializer(SECRET_KEY)
    try:
        user = timed_serializer.loads(token)
        api_user = User.get_by_id(user['id'])
    except (SignatureExpired, BadSignature) as e:
        abort(400, description=str(e))
    return True
```

**todo.py**

```
@auth.error_handler
def errorhandler():
    return jsonify(unauthorized="Cannot add Todo. Login required."), 401


class TodoCollection(Resource):

    @auth.login_required
    def post(self):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        args = self.request_parser.parse_args()
        if not args['name']:
            return make_response(
                {'invalid_request': "Invalid todo provided"}, 400
            )
        new_todo = Todo.create(**args)
        return (
            marshal(set_todo_creator(new_todo), todo_fields, 'new_todo'),
            201, {'Location': f'{new_todo.location}'}
        )
```

Comment: 401 is a bad request not an authentication error, probably because you are not serializing your json data correctly. You probably should use `json=` in your post to pass JSON https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/testing/#testing-json-apis

Comment: Implementing your suggestion makes the assertion go from a 401 status code to a 400 status code.

Comment: This is for debugging purposes only `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`, right? What if you remove that line and try again :p?